# SQL Server : column contains values like (1,2,3,4) - I need convert rows level A 1 2 3 4

Tags: sql-server

Question: in SQL Server, I have a column which contains values like `(1,2,3,4)`.

I need to convert this into:

```
 A
---
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

Comment: EXPECTED ANSWE A
1
2
3
4

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you use?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string/10914602#10914602

Comment: column having coma separated data want to get
1
2
3
4

Comment: Please try a query in the duplicate link, and if you still are stuck then drop a comment, and someone can reopen this question.

Comment: Just in case you are using SQL Server 2017, please refer to this: [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) if on any earlier version refer to the previous URL shown above. Both will split "1,2,3,4" into 4 rows